# Ubuntu Unable to locate package python-pymc

Tags: ubuntu

I'm in on Ubuntu and was trying to install python pymc package by running `sudo apt-get install -y python-pymc`

I received the error and cannot find much information by googling it

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pymc
```

Comment: See this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/672808/sudo-apt-get-install-python-pip-is-failing

Comment: hi I followed the instruction in the link but still got the same error message.